# Refresh page in controller symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this function in controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{lang}", name="homepage_lang")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $lang
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexLangAction(Request $request, $lang)
{

    if (isset($lang)){
        $newLang = $lang;
    }else{
        $localeLang = $request->getLocale();
        $newLang = $localeLang;
    }

    $this->get('session')->set("_locale", $newLang);

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
```

And Buttons in twig like this:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/es'" type="button">Español</button>
```

When I click the page refresh but not change the language, I have to click two times to change the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're changing the session in the controller, you'll need to reload after doing so. Try something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{lang}", name="homepage_lang")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $lang
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexLangAction(Request $request, $lang)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    if ($session->has("_locale") && $lang !== $session->get("_locale")) {
        $session->set("_locale", $lang);
        return new RedirectResponse('/' . $lang);
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's the redirect I was talking about, thank you for the code =) UpVoted

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do that is to use a link to the named route:

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage_lang') }}" title="Español">Español</a>
// if you are using bootstrap as a CSS framework then add the btn class
// so the link will look like a button
<a href="{{ path('homepage_lang') }}" title="Español" class="btn btn-primary">Español</a>
```

**Edit**

```
// for a route with parameters, you can use the following
<a href="{{ path('homepage_lang', {'lang': 'es'}) }}" title="Español" class="btn btn-primary">Español</a>
```

**Edit2**

Seems like the fact of changing the locale alone does not take effect immediatly, you need to somehow to do a **redirect**, refer to this question, you'll find more details, and you can even go with the best practice and add your event listener for this.

[User locale does not work at first request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648320/user-locale-does-not-work-at-first-request)

Comment: So how can I get the language value in controller?

Comment: Perfect! it works! thanks. but I have the same problem, I have to click two times for refresh the language. I click one and refresh the page but not the language.

Comment: Which means it wasn't the Javascript's fault in the link, let me take a deep look at that code in the action of the controller

Comment: @ximo12 I updated the answer, you can use a redirect to fix your issue, or maybe craft your own eventListener for this.